# String to Time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I have an input form for date, which gives me a string such as `06/01/2015`

Using it I need to get two variables in time format for the beginning of the day and the end of the day (00:00:00, and 23:59:59) in time (milliseconds) format such as `1433206800000`, `1433205690000`. Can someone give me a tip on how to do it in Javascript.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Or try vanilla JS which is quite capable of doing the job without any plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var d = new Date('your_date_string');

var start = Number(d.setHours(0,0,0,0));
var end = Number(d.setHours(23,59,59,999));
//OR
var start = d.setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime();
var end = d.setHours(23,59,59,999).getTime();
```

`start` and `end` are your variables

See setHours docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

Comment: or `d.setHours(0,0,0,0).getTime()`

Comment: If you use `Number(date)` that give the save as of `date.getTime()`

Comment: Yes, but it is using the official interface instead of having JS cast the value

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` class is smart enough to know how to convert standard date string formats into a date, so you can just create new date objects, and then use the `getTime()` function to get it in milliseconds.

```js
var dateStr = "06/01/2015",
    dayStartStr = " 00:00:00.000",
    dayEndStr = " 23:59:59.999";

var startDate = new Date(dateStr + dayStartStr);
var endDate = new Date(dateStr + dayEndStr);

console.log("start = " + startDate.getTime());
console.log("end = " + endDate.getTime());
```